# svelte mouseout event triggering inside element

Tags: html, event-handling, dom-events, svelte

I'm having problems with `mousein` and `mouseout` events triggering at unexpected times.

I am trying to use a GitHub svg icon and listen to when the mouse enters and leaves the icon. I'm not able to replicate it in [Svelte's REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d27f8bd350204dacba1d943ce8de36f4?version=3.55.1) though. In the REPL, the `mouseout` event will trigger once however moving my mouse through the element causes 4-5 `mouseout` in one pass. The `mouseout` is seemingly triggering when you leave the parent element and enter a child element so going from `mousein` on the `<a>` tag will trigger a `mouseout` when you enter the `<svg>` and `<path>` etc.

```
<a
    href="https://github.com/blahblahblah"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noreferrer"
    class="flex"
    on:mouseenter={handleGithub}
    on:mouseout={handleGithub}
    on:blur={handleGithub}
>
    <Icon type="github" />
    {#if githubHover}
        <p>GitHub</p>
    {/if}
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four mouse events related to this logic:

- `mouseenter`
- `mouseover`
- `mouseleave`
- `mouseout`

(There is no `mousein`.)

These [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling): `mouseover` & `mouseout`
These do not bubble: `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`

Bubbling events will trigger for all children in the hierarchy. If you do not want those events, use the non-bubbling versions. I.e. use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.